# Offline software for creating animated videos on Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, video, offline

I have used online cloud-based software like Moovly, Powtoon etc. for creating animated videos.

Any suggestions of a product that's free (like in "free beer"), offline & portable for Windows like those which we can make animated explanatory videos and can make flat design cartoon videos ?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to be able to do, 2D or 3D, existing Images or draw your own, cartoon like or photo realistic, flip card, fade or interpolate key frames? Asking for software "like" doesn't give enough information.

Comment: It looks like with the current description, Microsoft Paint fits already.